# JAVA Reverse Polish Notation using Stacks

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I wrote the following code based on the Wikipedia algorithm for RPN using Stacks:

```
public static void reversePolish(String[] x){
        Stack temp = new Stack();
        Integer one;
        Integer two;
        Integer result;
        for(String x1:x){
            switch(x1){
                case "+":
                    one = (Integer) temp.pop();
                    two = (Integer) temp.pop();
                    result = one+two;
                    System.out.println(one + "+"+two);
                    temp.push(result);
                    break;
                case "-":
                    one = (Integer) temp.pop();
                    two = (Integer) temp.pop();
                    result = one+two;
                    temp.push(result);
                    break;
                default :
                    temp.push(Integer.parseInt(x1));
                }
        }
        result = (Integer) temp.pop();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

However it gives me an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
    at java.util.Stack.pop(Stack.java:84)
    at TestingItOut.reversePolish(TestingItOut.java:57)
    at TestingItOut.main(TestingItOut.java:31)
C:\Users\Sanchit\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I have absolutely no idea what raises the error. HELP NEEDED

Comment: The stacktrace clearly shows the origin of the error: it's line 57 of the TestingItOut class, in the reversePolish method. It attempts to pop a value from the stack while the stack it's empty.

Comment: I passed {"2","1","+"} through the functions. Shouldn't the stack temp contain 2 and 1 by then?

Comment: Hold on just a second

Comment: i added a 'break;' in the default statement and it worked out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think throwing an `EmptyStackException` is the problem with your program - it runs perfectly well on my computer.

The reason that an `EmptyStackException` is thrown is probably the data you pass to `reversePolish()`.

As an example, a valid input should be:

```
"1", "2", "+", "3", "-", "6", "+"
```

Which means `1+2-3+6`. That is, if you wish to calculate a result with a binary operator and 2 operands, write the operands first and put the operator after them.

For more details, see [Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).

So why was an `EmptyStackException` thrown?

Your algorithm is simple: on an operand, push it into a stack, on an operator, pop the operands, calculate the result, and push it back. The problem is, if the program finds an operator and the stack does not contain sufficient operands, it still tries to pop the 2 required operands, and, `EmptyStackException`.

To polish the algorithm, you can first check the size of stack before popping, and print a human-readable message saying "There's not enough operands!" instead of throwing an `EmptyStackException`. The code could be like this: (partial)

```
case "+":
if (temp.size() < 2) {
    System.out.println("There's not enough operands!");
    return;
}
one = (Integer) temp.pop();
two = (Integer) temp.pop();
result = one + two;
System.out.println(one + " + " + two);
temp.push(result);
break;
```

Something more.

In case you haven't noticed, you've written `result = one + two;` under `case "-":`, which I take as a simple typo error. It should be `result = one - two`.

And if you run the program in an environment equal to or higher than Java 1.5, `Stack` should contain an generic type. In your case, it should be `Stack<Integer> temp = new Stack<Integer>();`. (If you're in Java 7 or newer, you can write `Stack<Integer> temp = new Stack<>();` for the sake of simplicity) And then you don't have to write `one = (Integer) temp.pop();`. `one = temp.pop()` is okay.

One more thing:

You simply write `result = (Integer) temp.pop();` at the end, which is still not the perfect thing.

Imaging the input being `"1", "2", "+", "3", "-", "6", "+", "7"`.

Translated, it's `1 + 2 - 3 + 6 7`. If you write this down and give it to your teacher, you will get a zero mark, because there's no operator connecting `6` and `7` -  that is, `7` is redundant.

However, if you give this to your program, it will output `7` instead of croaking some warnings. This is not the desired behavior.

So, the right thing to do is, write:

```
if (temp.size() == 1) {
    result = (Integer) temp.pop();
    System.out.println(result);
} else System.out.println("Redundant operands!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the break; command and all of it seemed to work. Not gonna fiddle around with it too much now!